# Sinon stub is not tracking consecutive methods invocation of the app

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner, sinon

I'm trying to make a basic integration test using Karma, Sinon and Mocha, but it's not return the expected result.

The application has a simple flow:

**todo.init** --> calls **todo.api.sendRequest({options Object}, callback)** --> calls **todo.setup**

**todo.setup is being invoked by the callback when we get the response back.(from the sendRequest method)

```
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('API integration', function(){

  it('todo.setup receives an array of todos when todo.init is called', function () {

    // create a stub
    sinon.stub(todo, 'setup');

    // start the application
    todo.init(); 

    expect(todo.setup.called).to.be.true;

  });

});
```

This test is not passing. If I invoke the todo.setup explicitly

```
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('API integration', function(){

  it('todo.setup receives an array of todos when todo.init is called', function () {

    // create a stub
    sinon.stub(todo, 'setup');

    // Invoke directly the todo.setup
    todo.setup();

    expect(todo.setup.called).to.be.true;

  });

});
```

The test passes now, but it's not the correct behavior because i'm invoking manually the method instead the application call.

Comment: Is `todo.setup()` being called asynchronously by `todo.api.sendRequest()`?

Comment: Can you share to code for `todo.api.sendRequest()`?